# Count length of array from separate .JSON file

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs

I am trying to count the number of times a 'chat' occurs in my separate JSON file using angularJS and jQuery.

```
"chat": [{
    "name":"a",
    "image":"content/img/chat.png",
    "text":"text here
    "align":"left"
},{
    "name":"b",
    "image":"content/img/chat2.png",
    "text":"text here.",
    "align":"right"
} ]
```

controller

```
var len = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
if ($scope.numLimitPlus < $scope.len) {
    $scope.numLimit++;
} else {
    $(".chatList button").click(function(){
        $(".chatList button").hide();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did mistake here `$scope.len` should be `len.chat.length`

```
var len = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
if ($scope.numLimitPlus < len.chat.length) { 
    $scope.numLimit++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yr json file should be a valid json. In yr case this is a correct version.

```
[
{
    "name": "a",
    "image": "content/img/chat.png",
    "text": "texthere",
    "align": "left"
},
{
    "name": "b",
    "image": "content/img/chat2.png",
    "text": "texthere.",
    "align": "right"
}
]
```

Read yr .json file inside controller using $http

```
  $http.get('path to yr .json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.length = data.length;
   });
```